# Help with creating files using REST API - SharePoint 2013

Tags: rest, create-document

```
_spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "_api/web/getfolderbyserverrelativeurl('/s/KM/box/pg/testRestDocs')/Files/add(url='" + docTitle + "',overwrite=true)";

$(function () { bindButtonClick(); }); function bindButtonClick() 
{ $("#btnSubmit").on("click", function () { createDocument(); }); 
} function createDocument() { var docTitle = $("#txtDocumentTitle").val() + ".txt"; var docContent = $("#txtDocumentContent").val(); 
var fullUrl = _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "_api/web/getfolderbyserverrelativeurl('/s/KM/box/pg/testRestDocs')/Files/add(url='" + docTitle + "',overwrite=true)"; 
$.ajax
({ url: fullUrl, 
  type: "POST", 
  data: docContent,
   headers: { "accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
    "content-type": "application/json;odata=verbose",
     "X-RequestDigest": $("#__REQUESTDIGEST").val() },
      success: onQuerySucceeded, error: onQueryFailed }); 
    } 
    function onQuerySucceeded() { $("#divResults").html("Document created!"); }
     function onQueryFailed() { alert('Error!'); }
```

---

My code fails to create a file

Comment: Is there any error?

Comment: No error.  It just doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

I’m going to assume you get an error in the console when the button is clicked.

You are missing the Authorization header with the Authz access token

This example taken from: [Working with folders and files with REST](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/sp-add-ins/working-with-folders-and-files-with-rest)

```
url: http://site url/_api/web/GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl('/Folder Name')/Files/add(url='a.txt',overwrite=true)
method: POST
body: "Contents of file"
Headers: 
    Authorization: "Bearer " + accessToken
    X-RequestDigest: form digest value
    content-length:length of post body
```

All write operations require the authorization token in SharePoint